# WCF Distributed Transaction Flow using normal return values

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions, distributed-transactions, msdtc

I have got a service that should use distributed transactions.

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
public bool ServiceMethod(int parameterPlaceHolder)
{
  return SomeOperationResult();
}
```

For reasons out of my responsibility, this service should never throw faults. On success it returns one value, on failure another (abstracted to a bool here for demo purposes).

The transaction flowing works.

However, the attribute implies that any result that is not an uncaught exception will complete the transaction. That's not the behavior I want. I want to control the outcome of the transaction myself. On returning false, I want to have the transaction fail.

I have tried various methods:

- The obvious one: setting `TransactionAutoComplete` to `false`. This means that I *have* to use a session based service. I don't want to. I don't need to. I'm perfectly fine with a single transaction scope per call. But it's not allowed. ("TransactionAutoComplete set to false requires the use of InstanceContextMode.PerSession.")
- The DIY one: setting `TransactionScopeRequired` to `false` and using my own. This means the flowed transactions no longer work and I create a new local transaction every time.
- The desperate one: Trying to get hold of the transaction that WCF creates and rolling it back on my own... this leads to my service throwing exceptions because it tries to AutoComplete a transaction that is long gone.

I'm out of ideas. Does anyone know how to create my own transaction scope, using a flowed distributed transaction, *not* using the Microsoft AutoComplete-On-Normal-Return pattern? I would like to not complete the transaction without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction scopes can nest. The entire transaction aborts if you don't completed any scope. So:

```
using (new TransactionScope()); //Doom transaction
```

Better comment this line.

You can also try to call stuff on `Transaction.Current` but I have no experience with that.

Comment: I do have an inner transaction scope that I only Complete on `true`. However, that leads to a ProtocolException for the caller: "The transaction under which this method call was executing was asynchronously aborted."